# Adding Additional Pumpkin To My Porter

Tags: techniques, flavor

I'm brewing a extract Pumpkin Porter kit and just transferred from primary to secondary. I tasted it and I could taste the spices but was wondering if it was too late to pumpkin it up a little. Could i add something now, If so what exactly would I add, Caned pumpkin? Or is it already too late?

Answer (score 1):

Secondary fermentation stage is a good time to add flavours to your beer.  Primary fermentation has already lowered the pH,  created ethanol, and used-up dissolved oxygen.  This makes your beer relatively inhospitable to a lot of microorganisms.  The large amount of carbon dioxide escaping the air-lock during primary fermentation can also remove some volatile flavours you may wish to keep.

Depending on what sort of pumpkin you add, there may be some more significant fermentation, but that's ok.  I'm not familiar with canned pumpkin (it's not sold here) but just a sliced, dry-roasted pumpkin could be added.  You will probably need to wait an extra week or so for it to settle out - I guess this depends on whether it's mashed, sliced, etc.

Pumpkin variety names probably don't translate cross-hemispheres, but use something with a lot of flavour, not necessarily "sweetness", something like a "Kent" perhaps might be a good addition.

[image: Kent pumpkin]